# MYSQL how to bind config ip to public ip in user table?

Tags: mysql

I have an AWS EC2 instance. I installed mysql in the ubuntu server and now I'm trying to connect to the installed DB on the ubuntu server.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why mysql will not start up on the IP I binded to the config file.

I run the following command:

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

couple things:

1. I edit the bind-ip-address to my public ip in this case: `54.62.33.334` instead of `127.0.0.1` cause this is a production server.
2. I replaced the default user of `mysql` with my created user `jason`

- I opened up my inbound network ports to 3306.

I created a user called "jason" and granted him access to all databases using the following command:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'jason'@'54.62.33.334';`

when I restart my mysql server using `sudo systemctl restart mysql` it throws me this error:

`Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

I run the following command to see the error.

`journalctl -xe`

it gives me this.

`Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 mysql-systemd-start[6378]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server: Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 mysql-systemd-start[6378]: 2020-07-02T02:51:53.747898Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'jason' ;  Please check that the user exists! Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 mysql-systemd-start[6378]: 2020-07-02T02:51:53.748587Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 mysql-systemd-start[6378]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues. Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 mysql-systemd-start[6378]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service. Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1 Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. Jul 02 02:51:53 ip-54.62.33.334 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server. -- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed -- Defined-By: systemd`

But I do have a user called `jason` I ran the following command to check if the user exists in my user table and it returns 1 which is true so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

`SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username');`

FYI: I'm able to connect to the DB just fine using root but I want to connect using user jason but I can't for some reason.

Any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. I've been trying to figure this out for the past 4-5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The my.cnf file lists the user in a `[mysqld]` (or `server` or a few other options) as the unix user of the system of which the server starts. Do not change this.

You can set `user=jason` in a `[client]` or `[mysql]` section of a config file which will refer to the database user `jason`. This needs to be in a configuration used by the application connecting to the server.

Rather thank binding to a public IP address you should look at using ssh tunneling to administer a public DB instance.

On SQL:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'username');
```

There's no need to put this in a subquery. A simple select is fine. Also the `(user,host)` combination is a distinct user.

Comment: so I have a question, in my config file I changed the ip to 0.0.0.0 I read everwhere this is not good for use in production but it works when I connect to it remotely or through my code. for the ip, should I use the public IP?

Comment: it should be a private IP. As per the answer you should use ssh tunneling to connect to the server. While public IP works for you it also works for every bot that connects. While you have correctly limited access of jason to a specific IP address are all other users of the database similarly contained? Also the version history of MySQL shows a continuous  flow of CVEs in most releases. Some are public without authentication. The never version released may disclose another one of these which will leave you vulnerable.

Comment: all users have a special password on them. What I don't understand though is I have another instance and it worked fine last time where I had all my users password protected and I binded the IP in the config file to the public ip of the website and the user to the user in my db table and it doesn't work. I'm wondering if it has to do with me having a newer version of mysql?

Comment: it looks like you haven't read the answer provided. You have `user=` set in the wrong config file section. `mysqld` != `mysql`. It also has no effect in the `mysql` section if users are connecting remotely.